# Dark-mode turned off on refeshing a page

Tags: javascript

My Dashboard has a dark mode(CSS) but when I refresh the page it turns class BODY dark-mode to light mode!

How I can save Dark-Mode when the page is refreshed?

```
NioApp.ModeSwitch = function () {
var toggle = $('.dark-switch');

if ($body.hasClass('dark-mode')) {
  toggle.addClass('active');
} else {
  toggle.removeClass('active');
}

toggle.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $body.toggleClass('dark-mode');
});};
```

Comment: you need to add your properties in local storage, because when ever you refresh the page, it will not persist any sort of data unless it is store somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store theme and get as you left it like

```
document.cookie = "theme=dark expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT /*Not to expire*/" //when switching dark mode

document.cookie = "theme=light expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT /*Not to expire*/" //when switching light mode
```

And than retrieve this by function

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

now you only have to get theme from cookies
when window ia loaded

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (getCookie("theme") == "light") {
        //Toggle To Light Theme By Function
    } else if (getCookie("theme") == "dark") {
        //Toggle To Dark Theme By Function
    }
});
```